# Islands, Bridges, and Loops

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

> There are $n$ islands with $n$ bridges connecting pairs of islands
>   (where $n\ge 2$). Prove that some sequence of distinct bridges forms a
>   loop.

I think induction is the way to go; it is clearly true for $n=2$, but I am confused about the inductive step. How should I connect $n$ and $n+1$?

Comment: Instead of induction you could use prove by contradiction and/or pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I would instead consider the maximal number of bridges *without* loops, and then note that $n$ is larger than that. For the maximal number of bridges without loops, it is obvious where to put the new bridge.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243707/the-number-of-edges-in-a-tree-is-n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that the result is true for $n$ bridges and $n$ islands, and that you have an arrangement of $n+1$ bridges and $n+1$ islands.

- If there is an island with exactly one bridge to it, consider the arrangement that remains after you remove that island and bridge.
- If there is an island with no bridge to it, consider the arrangement after you remove that island and any one bridge.
- Otherwise, each island has at least two bridges. Start at any island. Cross a bridge to another island. Keep moving from island to island, making sure that you always leave each island using a different bridge from the one by which you reached the island. You can do this indefinitely. (Why?) On the other hand, there are only finitely many islands, so eventually ...

Comment: If each island has at least two bridges then each island has exactly two bridges. It follows that the graph is in fact a disjoint union of cycles.

Comment: @Christian: I realize that, but the OP doesn't need to do so in order to get the desired result.

Comment: What about the case that there is an islang without any bridges? I know that for a simple graph with this hypothesis this isn't possible (since it is necessarily connected) but one may add this argument for completeness.

Comment: @M.U.: Good point; I’ve added that case.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now and know the solution to this problem!

Comment: @math12345: Excellent! You’re welcome.