# Prove the sum of degrees of the vertices minus 1 equals n minus 2

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that a tree T with n vertices has
$$\sum_{v∈V}^{} (deg
(v) − 1) = n − 2.$$

It seems like a really simple equation but I can't find any traces of it online.

Comment: Follows pretty directly from the classic result on the number of edges in a tree. For that result, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243707/the-number-of-edges-in-a-tree-is-n-1) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that a tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges.  (*Prove this if you haven't already*)

We also know the [Handshaking-Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) for a general simple graph that $\sum\limits_{v\in V}(\deg(v))=2|E|$

These two things together imply the following for a tree:

$\sum\limits_{v\in V}(\deg(v)) = 2|E|=2n-2$

$-n + \sum\limits_{v\in V}(\deg(v)) = -n + 2n-2$

$\sum\limits_{v\in V}(\deg(v)-1)=n-2$